# Ionic App is not working working after Integrated fabric Crashlytics

Tags: cordova, crashlytics, ionic4

I want to integrate fabric Crashlytics but it is not working for me. I have integrate chrashlytics but when i am importing Crashlytics in module then it is return me an error. I have add plugin link this

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=asdjfkjasldfjklajsdfkljasldjfl--variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=asdfasdfasdfasdfasd
npm install --save @ionic-native/fabric@4
```

then i have added Crashlytics in module.ts like this

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Crashlytics } from '@ionic-native/fabric/';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    Crashlytics,
    DatePipe,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

then i add Crashlytics in home.ts like this

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Crashlytics } from '@ionic-native/fabric';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe,
     private crashlytics: Crashlytics
    ){
      try {
        throw new Error("this is javascriptError");
      }
      catch (e) {
        this.crashlytics.addLog("Error while loading data");
        this.crashlytics.sendNonFatalCrash(e.message || e);
      }
    }
  myTime: String = this.datepipe.transform(new Date().toISOString(), 'hh:mm');;

  myDate: String = this.datepipe.transform(new Date().toISOString(), 'MMM dd, yyyy');;

}
```

and this is my error logs

```
vendor.js:75062 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at vendor.js:75062
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/fabric/index.js (vendor.js:75164)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:84)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (main.js:1036)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:84)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.js:1114)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:84)
    at Object.0 (main.js:1137)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:84)
    at checkDeferredModules (runtime.js:46)
```

please see this carefully and help me to solve it

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the Ionic Native documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#angular):

> For Angular, the import path should end with `/ngx`

So:

```
import { Crashlytics } from '@ionic-native/fabric';
```

should be:

```
import { Crashlytics } from '@ionic-native/fabric/ngx';
```

Comment: I am getting this error. Cannot find module '@ionic-native/fabric/ngx'.ts(2307)

Comment: I don't see any direct support for `fabric` in the [Ionic Native docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/), but there is for [Firebase Crashlytics](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-crashlytics) so try that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install:

`npm install @ionic-native/fabric@latest`

and import:

`import { Crashlytics } from '@ionic-native/fabric/ngx';`